# ping two server 2008 in different networks

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

i use vmware workstation8
i have two visual network (type:host-only)
VMnet1:
ip:192.168.163.1
subnet :255.255.255.0
VMnet2:192.168.131.1
Getway:255.255.255.0

on server 1 use VMnet1 :
i have only network card (I do not want add another network card):
ip:192.168.163.128
subnet:255.255.255.0
getway:192.168.163.1

on server 2 use VMnet2 :
i have only network card (I do not want add another network card):
ip:192.168.131.128
subnet:255.255.255.0
getway:192.168.131.1

i close all firewalls.
I do not want add another network card.
i can't ping server1 from server2 or server2 from from server1.please help me?
this video do it ( www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1MSjybswyc ) but i don't know how.
he go to administartive tools and i see he dont use routing rols.

Comment: I don't use VMware workstation myself but use ESXi extensively. Your routing needs to be performed on the gateway (host machine) however its not a great way to setup a lab as it's not 'real-life' what I've always done for my labs was install RRAS on both Server's and setup a VPN between them like you might do in a real environment and then sync over that.

Answer (score 0):

remove the gateways from the NIC's on both servers - As they are host only adapters I'm presuming you don't need the internet and ensure all firewalls are disabled then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

VMware Workstation host-only networking provides a network connection between the virtual machine and the host computer using a virtual Ethernet adapter that is visible to the host operating system.

You need a operating system acting as router between this two host-only network and you have to set it as default gateway for both virtual machine.

The operating system acting as router can be:

- A third virtual machine as reported in VMWare documentation https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_advanced_2hostonly_routing.html
- The operating system running VMWware workstation, the configuration of it depends from the OS software (linux, windows??? )